# Haskell `hdevtools is not executable!` error

Tags: unix, haskell, vim, ghci, hdevtools

## Problem

I'm trying to set up hdevtools for piping GHC errors into my editor linter (so that you don’t have to continually run `:r` in GHCi to see errors). I have run into a `hdevtools is not executable!` error.

## Question

Does anyone know what I’ve done wrong or what I can do to get this working? I'm not sure if this is a problem with the way I set up GHC and/or hdevtools, or if this is a problem with the permission settings of my directories or something...

## Background info

- Here is what the error and setup looks like:
  [image]
- To get to this point, I followed the the instructions from http://seanhess.github.io/2015/08/05/practical-haskell-editors.html. Basically, I ran `brew install ghc`, `brew install haskell-stack`, `stack setup`, `stack install hdevtools`, and updated my path as show in the picture above ^
- I'm brand new to Haskell. Been tinkering for a couple weeks.
- I'm on OSX
- It should be unrelated, but I’m using Syntastic with Vim + [vim-hdevtools](https://github.com/bitc/vim-hdevtools).

Comment: make sure  `which hdevtools` shows `~/.local/bin/hdevtools`, make sure to load a new shell or do an `export PATH...` in your old shell

Comment: @jberryman `which hdevtools` shows nothing so it looks like I've done something wrong; I'm not sure why though as `ls ~/.local/bin` outputs `hdevtools` and I have `export PATH="~/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc:~/.local/bin:$PATH"` in my `.bash_profile`. Any ideas?

Comment: have you started a new bash since? (`source ~/.bash_profile` should do as well)

Comment: @Carsten Yep. No dice.

Comment: Try `export PATH="$HOME/..."` instead of `export PATH="~/..."`.  `~` is not expanded inside double quotes.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yay! That did the trick. Thank you. If you want to re-post this as an "Answer", I'll pick it so you get the points.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I had a similar issue using the ghc provided by the ppa:hvr package which installs the ghc in `/usr/opt/ghc/`

I linked

- `/opt/ghc/7.10.3/bin/` -> `/home/epsilonhalbe/bin/ghc/`
- `/home/epsilonhalbe/.local/bin` -> `/home/epsilonhalbe/bin/util`

then i added the following to my `.vimrc`

```
" ADJUST PATH {{{
if (index(split($PATH,':'),'/home/epsilonhalbe/bin') < 0)
    let $PATH = '/home/epsilonhalbe/bin' . ':' . $PATH
endif
if (index(split($PATH,':'),'/home/epsilonhalbe/bin/ghc') < 0)
    let $PATH = '/home/epsilonhalbe/bin/ghc' . ':' . $PATH
endif
if (index(split($PATH,':'),'/home/epsilonhalbe/bin/util') < 0)
    let $PATH = '/home/epsilonhalbe/bin/util' . ':' . $PATH
endif
" }}}
```

maybe this helps.